# SSIS: Data Flow stopping after 5000 rows

Tags: ssis

I have an oledb source which i have hooked up to a script component.  The Script component is configured to the oledbdestination.  There are 70 rows which I am importing to the destination.  If i select the top 100 rows then I am able to succussfully import the data.  However, if i try to select the entire Table from teh source I get

The following Error:  Object ref not set to an instance of an object.

Any idea why?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try placing a data inspector inbetween the two tasks and you can look at the data.  You right-click on the flow to insert it.

I'd also look at the 5000th row of your source to see if there is some missing data.

Comment: how do you add one? i dont see that option

Comment: In the data flow - "Data viewer"